# Put request in POSTMAN, laravel

Tags: laravel, postman, put

I am using the postman for an api creation for my laravel project.
I have made POST requesting for uploading the video but now I am trying to make a PUT request.Other things are being updated in the table using it like title and name but I am not able to use any option to upload the file(image) for PUT request.And if I use form-data then nothings happens in this case.

Comment: select `form-data` and select file type from the key box and change `Text` to `File`

Comment: Just remove the `Content-Type` from the header in the input and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

You should be required the following changes.

`1) In Headers`

The `Content-type` field has been set as `multipart/form-data` in Headers.

2) Choose the `File` option instead of `text` from the dropdown on the right side.

3) add `_method: PUT` in form-data

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For `PUT` calls, try adding data in `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: but there is also no option for uploading any file

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **POST** method for file uploading. cause **PUT** method not supporting file uploading. [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17560) is issue in official github repo of laravel. you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17560#issuecomment-276132380) reply from laravel

Answer (score 1):

If using formdata, add this Key: _method and value: PUT, in the formdata. Then use POST as the request.

**NB**: This also supports Image uploading, give the key the name you want, then change text to File

Answer (score 0):

select `form-data` and select file type from the key box and change `Text` to `File`.

[image: Check the Image]

Comment: this works fine with POST request but not with PUT.

Comment: Ok..then change method to POST

Answer (score 0):

In postman, you can simply send a PUT request by changing the Request method near URL Bar.

For uploading files, select "form-data" as input in postman then you will see a panel to enter key-value pairs. Initially, you will notice that both the fields take text as input.

To upload a file from this panel, in the left box (where you are supposed to enter key name) check the rightmost corner. You can see the type of the box and then change it to file.

As soon as you change the key type, the value field will ask you to upload a file.

Edit 1: 
You can see in the screenshot here, where you need to change it from "Text" to "File"
[image]

Comment: multipart/form-data in header and form-data in body are not working in PUT request.I have already tried with method POST and mentioned _method PUT in key field but this is also not working.

Comment: and x-www-form-urlencodedin this type we can only give simple data other than files and images.So please let me know any other solution for PUT request.

Comment: If that is the case, your API server is not accepting the multipart/form-data in the "PUT" method. Laravel/PHP doesn't support it at the moment. You should change the request to the "POST" method.

As per this issue here (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17560), PHP doesn't add objects to $_FILE variable when the request method is set to "PUT"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just:

1. Select POST method
2. Set `_method = PUT` in the body of `Form-data`
   [image]